# Migrate data from Lotus Notes to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, lotus-notes

We are migrating several applications from Lotus Notes to SharePoint.  The applications consist of standard document libaries, lists, and forums.  What tools are available either free or commercial to migrate the data from Lotus Notes to SharePoint?  Are there any tools built into Lotus Notes to export data?

Comment: I think you have a better chance at getting an answer on ServerFault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the version to SharePoint you need to migrate.

If it's SharePoint 2007, there is a free tool provided by Microsoft named Microsoft Transporter Suite.

If it's another version of SharePoint, you can go for whichever third party tool you can afford.
eg tool, Quest & avepoint.